# Geometric inequality $180^{\circ}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\le \angle{AMB}$

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

> Point $M$ is located inside a regular $n$-gon. Prove that there exist different vertices $A$ and $B$ that 
>   $$180^{\circ}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\le \angle{AMB}\le 180^{\circ}$$

**My work so far:**

Let $d(M,A_iA_j) -$ the distance from a point $M$ to $A_iA_j$. Let $A,B$ such that   $d(M,AB)=\min d(M,A_iA_j)$.

I want to prove that $180^{\circ}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\le \angle{AMB}$. I need help here.

Comment: Does the regular polygon have $n$ sides?

Comment: @Element118, Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a regular $n-$gon inscribed in a circle with centre $O$. $A$ and $B$ are two of it's vertices and $M$ is a point located on/in any one of the $n$ equilateral triangles

It can be seen by exterior angle theorem, that for this regular $n-$ gon, $\frac{360}{n} \leq \angle{AMB} \leq 180^{\circ}.$

But we are required to prove that $180 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{n}) \leq \angle{AMB} \leq 180^{\circ}.$

So, by placing the point $M$ inside one of the $n$ equilateral triangles, we just need to to prove that $\frac{360}{n} \leq 180\cdot (1-\frac{1}{n})\Rightarrow n \geq 3$, which is indeed true for all regular polygons.